# How to get role id in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I was creating a `createrole` command and I wanted to show some info about the role, such as the name, color, and id, but how did I get the role id? I tried looking on this site, Reddit, and the API reference but I couldn't find an answer.

This is what I have now:

```
@bot.command(name='createrole')
async def createrole(ctx, *, content):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name=content)
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='content')
    roleid = role.id
    description = f'''
    **Name:** <@{roleid}>
    **Created by:** {ctx.author.mention}
    '''
    embed = discord.Embed(name='New role created', description=description)
    await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

Comment: Stupid question, but isn't the id of the role saved in ```roleid``` already?

Comment: Nope it says:
```'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Fix:

Right now you are passing the string `'content'` to your `get` function instead of the variable with the name `content`. Try replacing the following line:
`role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='content')`

with this:

`role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=content)`

**Much more efficient and less error prone way of doing it:**

`await guild.create_role` returns the role object created, meaning you don't need to refetch it by name and can just do this:

```py
@bot.command(name='createrole')
async def createrole(ctx, *, content):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = await guild.create_role(name=content)  
    roleid = role.id
    description = f'''
    **Name:** <@{roleid}>
    **Created by:** {ctx.author.mention}
    '''
    embed = discord.Embed(name='New role created', description=description)
    await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```